# Pagination issue in my wordpress site. Some array is showing up

Tags: php, wordpress

http://larasaget.com/works/sculpture/

You can see it in the bottom of the page Array ( [0] => Resource id #388 [1] => [2] => 5 )
I am not sure how this originated but the pagination is working fine. Only needs to remove the array.
Here is the code from the page template.

ajax-works.php

```
            <?php

            $rootD = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 

                    include_once($rootD.'/wp-config.php');


            if(is_file(dirname(__FILE__) .'/ajaxpaging.php')){  
                include_once(dirname(__FILE__) .'/ajaxpaging.php');
            }elseif(is_file(dirname(__FILE__) .'/../ajaxpaging.php')){  
                include_once(dirname(__FILE__) .'/../ajaxpaging.php');
            }elseif(is_file(dirname(__FILE__) .'/../../ajaxpaging.php')){
                include_once(dirname(__FILE__) .'/../../ajaxpaging.php');
            }   


            $ajax_pageing = new get_pageing_ajax(); 

            global $post;
             $pageid=$post->ID;;

            define(TEMPLATE_URL,get_template_directory_uri()."/");
            define(SITE_URL,get_bloginfo('url')."/");       

            $ajax_page          =   TEMPLATE_URL."ajax_works.php";
            $listdivid          =   "gallery_div";
            $perpage            =   "6";

            if(isset($_REQUEST[gallery_id]) && $_REQUEST[gallery_id]!=""){
              $gallery_id=$_REQUEST[gallery_id];

             }else{
                if($pageid==117)// Performance
                    $gallery_id=2;
                elseif($pageid==374)//Paper
                    $gallery_id=3;
                elseif($pageid==361)//press
                    $gallery_id=4;
                else //Sculpture
                    $gallery_id=1;


             }


             $pg_query_string="&gallery_id=".$gallery_id;

             $selgallery= "select * from ls_ngg_gallery where gid = ".$gallery_id;
             $gres=mysql_query($selgallery);
             if(mysql_num_rows($gres)>0)
                $galval=mysql_fetch_array($gres);


             $sel='SELECT * FROM ls_ngg_pictures WHERE exclude != 1 AND galleryid = '. $gallery_id .' ORDER by pid DESC';
             $res = $ajax_pageing->number_pageing($sel,$perpage,0,'N','Y',"",$ajax_page,$pg_query_string,$listdivid);

               ?>  
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="pagetitle"><h1><?php the_title()?></h1></div>


                                    <div class="works">
                                    <?php $total=mysql_num_rows($res[0]);
                                        if($total>0)
                                        {?>
                                            <div class="row">
                                            <?php
                                            while($val=mysql_fetch_array($res[0])){
                                            $secondesc= nggcf_get_field($val[pid], "Second Description");
                                            $thirddesc= nggcf_get_field($val[pid], "Third Description");                                 

                                            ?>
                                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">


                                                <a rel="lightbox[work_group]" href="<?php echo site_url() . '/' .$galval['path'] . '/' . $val['filename'];?>"
                                                 title="<?php echo $val[alttext]?><br /><?php echo $val[description]?><br /><?php echo $secondesc;?><br />
                                                 <?php echo $thirddesc?> "><img src="<?php echo site_url() . '/' .$galval['path'] . '/thumbs/thumbs_' . $val['filename']?>" 
                                                  class="workimage" alt="work_group: image <?php echo $i?> 0f <?php echo $total?> thumb"/></a>



                                                  <div class="text-center worktitle">
                                                  <?php echo $val[alttext]?>
                                                  </div>


                                                </div> <!-- .col-lg-4 .col-md-4 .col-sm-6 .col-xs-6 -->
                                            <?php }?>    
                                            </div> <!-- end .row -->

                                            <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 text-right">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php
                                        }?>
                                    </div>







                                    <div class="clear"></div>


                                    <?php print_r($res); ?>
                                </div>
```

ajaxpaging.php

```
            <?php



            class get_pageing_ajax{

            var $record_per_page=10;

            var $pages=5;

            var $tbl,$file_names,$order,$query;



            ///////// GET THE VALUE OF START VARIABLE////////////////



                function start()

                {

                    if($_REQUEST["start"])

                        return  $start=$_REQUEST["start"];

                    else

                        return  $start=0;

                }



            //////////////  END OF START FUNCTION///////////////////    



            //////////////  GET THE CURRENT FILE NAME ///////////////////



                function file_names()

                {

                    $pt=explode("/",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

                    $totpt=count($pt);

                    return $this->file_names=$pt[$totpt-1];

                }



            //////////////  END OF FILE_NAME FUNCTION///////////////////    



            //////////////  DISPLAY THE NUMERIC PAGING WITHOUT RECORD DETAIL///////////////////



                function number_pageing_nodetail($query,$record_per_page='',$pages='')

                {

                        return $this->number_pageing($query,$record_per_page,$pages,"N");

                }



                function number_pageing_bottom_nodetail($query,$record_per_page='',$pages='')

                {

                        return $this->number_pageing($query,$record_per_page,$pages,"N","Y");

                }



                function number_pageing_bottom($query,$record_per_page='',$pages='')

                {

                        return $this->number_pageing($query,$record_per_page,$pages,"","Y");

                }



            //////////////  END OF NUMERIC PAGING FUNCTION ///////////////////  



                function runquery($query)

                {

                    return  mysql_query($query);

                }



                function table($result,$titles,$fields,$passfield="",$edit,$delete,$parent="")

                {



                        if($parent=="")

                            $parent="Y";



                        if($passfield=="")

                            $passfield="id";



                        $cont="<table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3' border='0' class='borders'><tr>";

                        foreach($titles as $K=>$V)

                        {

                            $cont1.="<td";

                            $cont1.=(is_numeric($V))?" width='$V%' align='center'><strong>$K</strong></td>":" align='center'><strong>$V</strong></td>";

                        }

                        $cont.=$cont1."</tr>";

                        $cont.="<tr><td colspan='".count($titles)."'><script language=javascript>

                                msg=\"<table border=0 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=1 class='bg1' width='100%'><TR>$cont1</TR></table>\";



                                </script>

                        <script src='topmsg.js'></script>           

                        </td></tr>";

                        $j=0;

                        while($gets=mysql_fetch_object($result))

                        {

                            $j=1;

                            $cont.="<tr onMouseOver=\"this.className='yellowdark3bdr'\" onmouseout=\"this.className=''\">";

                            foreach($fields as $K=>$V)

                            {

                                $cont.="<td align='center'>";

                                $tmps=explode(",",$V);

                                $newval="";

                                foreach($tmps as $val)

                                {

                                    $newval.=$gets->$val." ";

                                }

                                $cont.=(is_numeric($K))?$newval:"<a href='$K?$passfield=".$gets->$passfield."' onMouseOver=\"smsg('View Detail of ".addslashes($newval)."');return document.prs_return\" onMouseOut=\"nosmsg('Done');return document.prs_return\">".$newval."</a>";

                                $cont.="&nbsp;</td>";

                            }

                            $cont.="<td><INPUT name='button' type='button' onClick=\"";

                            $cont.=($parent=="N")?"window":"parent.body";

                            $cont.=".location.href='$edit?$passfield=".$gets->$passfield."'\" value='Edit' onMouseOver=\"smsg('Edit This Record -> $newval');return document.prs_return\" onMouseOut=\"nosmsg('Done');return document.prs_return\">&nbsp;&nbsp;<INPUT onClick=\"deleteconfirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Record?.','$delete?$passfield=".$gets->$passfield."');\" type='button' value='Delete' onMouseOver=\"smsg('Delete This Record -> $newval');return document.prs_return\" onMouseOut=\"nosmsg('Done');return document.prs_return\">&nbsp;</td>";

                            $cont.="</tr>";

                        }



                        if($j==0)

                        {

                            $cont.="<tr><td colspan='".(count($fields)+1)."' align='center'><font color='red'><strong>No Record To Display</strong></font></td></tr>";

                        }

                        echo    $cont.="</table>";

                }

            ///////////// NUMERIC FUNCTION WITH RECORD DESTAIL//////////////////////////////////////

                function number_pageing($query,$record_per_page='',$pages='',$detail='',$bottom='',$simple='',$cur_page="",$query_string="",$divid="")

                {

                    $this->file_names();

                    $this->query=$query;



                    if($record_per_page>0)

                        $this->record_per_page=$record_per_page;



                    if($pages>0)

                        $this->pages=$pages;



                    $this->query=$query;

                    $result=$this->runquery($this->query);

                    $totalrows= mysql_affected_rows();                                      



                    $start=$this->start();



                    $order=$_GET['order'];

                    $this->query.=" limit $start,".$this->record_per_page;  

                    $result=$this->runquery($this->query);

                    $total= mysql_affected_rows();



                    $total_pages=ceil($totalrows/$this->record_per_page);

                    $current_page=($start+$this->record_per_page)/$this->record_per_page;

                    $loop_counter=ceil($current_page/$this->pages);

                    $start_loop=($loop_counter*$this->pages-$this->pages)+1;

                    $end_loop=($this->pages*$loop_counter)+1;



                    if ($current_page > 2)

                        $start_loop = $current_page-2 ;



                    if ($total_pages >= $current_page + 3)  

                    {

                        $end_loop = $current_page + 3;

                    }



                    if($end_loop>$total_pages)

                        $end_loop=$total_pages+1;



                    $tmpva="";

                    foreach($_REQUEST as $V=>$K)

                    {

                        if($V!="start")

                            $tmpva.="&".$V."=".$K;

                    }



                    //$this->tbl="<table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td width='15%' align='left'>&nbsp;&nbsp;";



                    $this->tbl="<ul class='pagination'>";







                    if ($cur_page == "")

                        $cur_page = $this->file_names;



                    if($start>0)

                    { 

                        //$this->tbl.="<a class='paging' href='".$cur_page."?start=".($start-$this->record_per_page).$query_string."' class='boldbluelink' onMouseOver=\"smsg('Previous Page');return document.prs_return\" onMouseOut=\"nosmsg('Done');return document.prs_return\">&lt;&lt;  Previous</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 



                        $this->tbl.="

                        <li class='num_off' onclick=call_ajax_view('".$cur_page."','start=".($start-$this->record_per_page).$query_string."','".$divid."')><a>&laquo;</a></li>";







                    }

                    else

                    {

                        $this->tbl.="<li class='num_on'><a>&laquo;</a></li>";

                    } 



                    //$this->tbl.="&nbsp;</td><td width='70%' align='center' class='bluenormaltahoma'>&nbsp;";

                    if($detail!="N" and $simple !="N")

                        $this->tbl.="Result ".($start+1)." - ".($start+$total)." of ".$totalrows." Records<BR>";

                    if($simple!='N')

                    {



                        for($i=$start_loop;$i<$end_loop;$i++) 

                        {

                            if($current_page==$i)   

                            {

                                //$this->tbl.="<span class='currnet_page'>[".$i."]</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 

                                $this->tbl.="<li class='num_on_active'><a>".$i."</a></li>";

                            }   

                            else 

                            { 

                                //$this->tbl.="<a class='paging' href='".$cur_page."?start=".($i-1)*$this->record_per_page.$query_string."' class='boldbluelink' onMouseOver=\"smsg('View Page Number $i');return document.prs_return\" onMouseOut=\"nosmsg('Done');return document.prs_return\">".$i."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 



                                $this->tbl.="<li class='num_off' onclick=call_ajax_view('".$cur_page."','start=".($i-1)*$this->record_per_page.$query_string."','".$divid."')><a>".$i."</a></li>";





                            }

                        }

                    }



                    //$this->tbl.="&nbsp;</td><td width='15%' align='right'>";

                    if($start+$this->record_per_page<$totalrows) 

                    { 

                        //$this->tbl.="<a class='paging' href='".$cur_page."?start=".($start+$this->record_per_page).$query_string."' class='boldbluelink' onMouseOver=\"smsg('Next Page');return document.prs_return\" onMouseOut=\"nosmsg('Done');return document.prs_return\">Next  &gt;&gt;</a>"; 



                        $this->tbl.="<li class='num_off' onclick=call_ajax_view('".$cur_page."','start=".($start+$this->record_per_page).$query_string."','".$divid."')><a>&raquo</a></li>";



                    } 

                    else

                    {

                        $this->tbl.="<li class='num_on'><a>&raquo;</a></li>";   

                    }



                    $this->tbl.="</ul>

                              ";



                    if($bottom=="Y")

                    {

                        return $result=array($result,$this->tbl,$total_pages);

                    }

                    else

                    {

                        echo $this->tbl;        

                        return $result;

                    }

                }   

            //////////////  SIMPLE NEXT-PRI PAGING ///////////////////  

                function pageing($query,$record_per_page="",$pages="")

                {

                        return $this->number_pageing($query,$record_per_page,$pages,'','','N');

                }

            //////////////  END OF SIMPLE PAGING FUNCTION///////////////////    



            //////////////  WRITE ALL,A TO Z CHARACTER WITH CURRENT PAGE LINK ///////////////////

                function order()

                {

                    $this->file_names();

                    $this->order.="<TR><TD><a class=la href='".$this->file_names."' onMouseOver=\"smsg('View All Records');return document.prs_return\" onMouseOut=\"nosmsg('Done');return document.prs_return\">All</a></TD><TD class=lg>|</TD>";

                    for($i=65;$i<91;$i++)

                    {       

                        $this->order.="<TD><a class=la href='$file_names?order=".chr($i)."' onMouseOver=\"smsg('View By ".chr($i)."');return document.prs_return\" onMouseOut=\"nosmsg('Done');return document.prs_return\">".chr($i)."</a></TD><TD class=lg>|</TD>";

                    }

                    return $this->order.="</TR>";

                }



                function MakeCombo($query,$value="",$fill_value,$comboname)

                {

                    if($value=="")

                        $value=$fill_value;



                    $run=$this->runquery($query);

                    $totlist=mysql_affected_rows();

                    $Combo="<select name='$comboname'>";

                    $Combo.="<option value=''>----------Select-----------</option>";

                    for($i=0;$i<$totlist;$i++)

                    {

                        $get=mysql_fetch_object($run);

                        $Combo.="<option value='".$get->$value."'>".$get->$fill_value."</option>";

                    }

                    $Combo.="</select>";

                    echo $Combo;

                }

            }



            ?>
```

Comment: `<?php print_r($res); ?>` Maybe ? Just maybe...

Comment: @Rizier123 Isn't that the function printing the pagination section. If I remove it I'll lose the whole pagination section. I also tried to echo but no luck.

Comment: Remove it and look :)

Comment: @Rizier123 Lost the whole pagination section

Comment: Show us your `ajaxpaging.php`, it probably has some method to output it as HTML.

Comment: @ReneKorss added it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<?php print_r($res); ?>
```

with

```
<?php $ajax_pageing->number_pageing($sel,$perpage,0,'N','N',"",$ajax_page,$pg_query_string,$listdivid); ?>
```

And remove call to `number_pageing` on top of file.

Calling `number_pageing` method will `echo` it. No need to `echo` or `print_r` it again.

Comment: Done it. Again lost the pagination. This is the part I also don't understand.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed my mistake. Change 5th parameter to "N". This will `echo` it. Otherwise it returns `array`. This is `$bottom` variable.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. It fixed the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: I accepted it but I am new I can't up vote it. I will do it future. :)